# Is there some way to import c *.lib in python (or Ironpython) directly without any wrapping ?

Tags: python, c, ironpython, .lib

As the title, is there some way to import c *.lib in python (or Ironpython) directly without any wrapping? (such as *.dll including wrapping functions)

Comment: Have you done any research into this yourself yet? Have you seen the [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) (in the Python standard library)?

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow questions work; it is not a forum conversation. Don't change the question after you get an answer, post a **new** question instead.

Comment: OK. I am sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Both CPython and IronPython come with the [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), which lets you load DLLs directly:

```
from ctypes import *

print hex(windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleA(None))
```

Do read the module documentation carefully, it includes a tutorial on how to pass in various C types correctly.

Comment: And, after following the tutorial, you haven't been able to figure out how to call the `Init` function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already got errors by executing windll.LoadLibrary. The Init function could obviously only be called after import the .dll successfully.

Comment: According to the documentation `LoadLibrary()` only accepts DLL **names**, not filepaths. You need to make sure that the DLL can be found by Windows first, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(v=vs.85).ASPX

Comment: Thank you. I used LoadLibrary() with filepaths which worked. But for this case, whether filepath nor name works.

Comment: And the DLL can be loaded in other programs? This does not look like a Python problem to me.

Comment: Thank you. It can be loaded in other programs which are in c++.